# Page popup from bottom flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have an app and i wanted to add page thad slides from the bottom up, ultill three quarters of the screen, just as shown in the picture here[image]

and if you press the arrow it will go back again.

[image]

As you can see, once you press the food system, that threee quarter page will pop up. I have the onclock and everython ready but i just dont know what to use once you press it.

Comment: you can use bottomsheet and manage it on button click

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use 'showModalBottomSheet' widget. [more info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

```
showModalBottomSheet(
     context: context,
     builder: (builder) {
          return childWidget;
     },
```

and for 3/4 of screen height, you can set something like this:

```
double mWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double mHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Widget childWidget(){
     return Container {
        width: mWidth,
        height: mHeight  * 0.75,
     }
}
```